# java bean and JDBC assignment

Tags: java, jdbc, javabeans

Q.1)write  a bean which will have a property called model representing model name of mobile.
when user enters some text in it, the price of that model should be displayed in canvas.

Q.2)write a jdbc program that accepts a subject name as command line argument and 
displays the highest marks scores in that subject [make sutable assumptions for table details]

Comment: And you have tried what exactly? Assuming you bothered to try, where did you fail? The purpose of this website is to help one another, not to do someone else's homework

Comment: 1) Tag as homework. 2) Write some code. 3) Update your question with a specific, objectively answerable question about the problem you're having with that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/index.html) tutorial on Java Beans and [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) tutorial on JDBC.